# Removing top cap and stem from Acros headset?

Tags: headset, stem

I recently bought a used Canyon Ultimate that has an Acros headset on it. I'm trying to remove the stem but for the life of me can't figure out how to take it off. The top cap doesn't have a vertical bolt but instead is just hollow.

I've removed the stem bolts and the stem freely rotates on the steerer tube,but I can't take it off because of the top cap. I've never encountered this type of headset before, surely I must be doing something stupid?

Picture of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Just wondering how to pre-load the headset with this configuration.

Comment: There's a small, recessed  horizontal Torx T6 screw on the bottom left of the headset that you can hardly see in the picture. Tightening this pre-loads the headset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, yes I am an idiot. You literally just pry the top cap off.

Comment: Good work finding your answer.  Do remember to mark this as "accepted" else Community will periodically make this one bubble to the top again and again.